# PHP: Choose region for datetime setting

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, region

In PHP, we can set a region for the `datetime`. The problem is, I know the city, I know the region, but the region is not recognized. How to choose a region which is programmatically recognized but fits the region we want?

For example, I need to find a region for Wiltshire. Wiltshire is not recognized, different from California or New York.

Comment: don't expect every little hole-in-the-wall village/town to have a timezone definition. pick the nearest "big" city that's in the same timezone and use that.

Comment: I guess Walishire is located in London, so you can use timezone of london.

Comment: I thought there maybe a tool for that to make us sure. 
Wiltshire, not Walishire

Comment: PHP knows all common time zone definitions. However, for most states (or countries outside the US), there is only one definition that covers it. If you don't know what timezone a city is in, you have to look it up. There is no way around that. It's basically the same as setting a timezone on your local computer.

Comment: There is this list: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php but no tool

Comment: Do you need timezone information of user while they signup to your application?

Comment: No. I need it to set up a self built script

Answer (score 1):

You can also set your default time zone after picking your region.

How to select and set your time zone visit this : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list supported time zones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

You just need to pick the one in which you're located (Europe/London).

Comment: I wish there is an easier one, but that doesn't seem so